# Laravel Blade parse error when I use @if statement with custom blade components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Following, I have a code for displaying a list of packages. Data is gathered from a config file and I checked the data, it fits. If statement is needed to determine if the packages has `$package->monthlyPrice` and `$package->yearly` (**isset()**). Since only packages has these are paid ones, I check for `if key == free`
The component works fine provided there is no if statement. But as soon as I added the following if statement, it brakes and gives me foollowing error:
**syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH), expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)**

**I use laravel 8.***

```
<x-container>
    <x-slot name="overheading">
        {{$data->overheading}}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="h1">
        {{$data->h1}}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="content">
       <div class="row">
            @foreach($data->list as $key => $package)
                @if($key == 'free')
                    <x-rectangle-price class="{{$key}}" :name="$package->name" :link="$package->link">
                @else
                    <x-rectangle-price class="{{$key}}" :yearly="$package->yearly" :monthlyprice="$package->monthlyPrice" :name="$package->name" :link="$package->link">
                @endif
                    <x-slot name="title"></x-slot>
                    <x-slot name="feats">
                        @foreach($package->package_feats as $feat)
                            <li class="{{$feat->active}}"> {!!$feat->content!!} </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </x-slot>
                </x-rectangle-price>
            @endforeach
       </div>
    </x-slot>
</x-container>
```

Normally this type of if statement works fine with plain html components. Laravel 8 components however has this issue. Last time I solved it via adding the unset variables to the config as null however It is not a good practice. @isset is also not working

Comment: Also forgot to mention an if statement without 'elseif' or 'else' also works.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use @if statement to conditionate the opening of an x component.
You should reword your code to avoid it

```
<x-container>
    <x-slot name="overheading">
        {{$data->overheading}}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="h1">
        {{$data->h1}}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="content">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($data->list as $key => $package)
                @if($key == 'free')
                    <x-rectangle-price class="{{$key}}" :name="$package->name" :link="$package->link">
                        <x-slot name="title"></x-slot>
                        <x-slot name="feats">
                            @foreach($package->package_feats as $feat)
                                <li class="{{$feat->active}}"> {!!$feat->content!!} </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </x-slot>
                    </x-rectangle-price>
                @else
                    <x-rectangle-price class="{{$key}}" :yearly="$package->yearly" :monthlyprice="$package->monthlyPrice" :name="$package->name" :link="$package->link">
                        <x-slot name="title"></x-slot>
                        <x-slot name="feats">
                            @foreach($package->package_feats as $feat)
                                <li class="{{$feat->active}}"> {!!$feat->content!!} </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </x-slot>
                    </x-rectangle-price>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </x-slot>
</x-container>
```

Comment: I have tried this before and I get 
syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) 
in this case.

Comment: @HazarcanDoğaBakan edited the answer, this should work. if you still have an error it should be from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Missed `{{ }}` in statement, not problem of `@if` or `@isset`.

```
@if($key == 'free')
    <x-rectangle-price class="{{$key}}" :name="{{$package->name}}" :link="{{$package->link}}">
@else
    <x-rectangle-price class="{{$key}}" :yearly="{{$package->yearly}}" :monthlyprice="{{$package->monthlyPrice}}" :name="{{$package->name}}" :link="{{$package->link}}">
@endif
```

Comment: As you can see here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components, curly braces are not necessary for passing data to the components.